# TextView link text is not visible

Tags: android, kotlin, hyperlink, textview, invisible

I have a `TextView` that shows all inserted text except for the links, but the place where they should be is still clickable and takes me to the desired destination. What would be making the link itself invisible?

From string resource

```
<string name="credits">Video from <a href="http://youtube.com">Youtube</a></string>
```

From layout

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:fontFamily="@font/abril_fatface"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="12sp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="75dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:text="@string/credits"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

From activity

```
textCredits.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause might be the equality of text color and background. Try to set another color to the links using:

```
android:textColorLink="@color/someColor"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a color like this this

```
android:textColorLink="#fff"
```

And

```
android:autoLink="true"
```

Comment: From what I understand, you cant use movementMethod and autolink together.. plus the link works without it.